# Ubuntu 18.04 Process "sleep" has high CPU Useage

Tags: suspend, 18.04, cpu

I'll come back to my 8 core PC after many hours of being up and find my fans running high and CPU average at 28% where it would normally at 13%. When I open gnome System Monitor I see a process called "sleep" sucking up my CPU speed. As soon as I select the process it gets scared and closes. My CPU then returns to normal and my fan's slow back to normal. Whats going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to find the parent(s) of the sleep command. Next time this happens open a terminal and type `top`. The offending sleep command should be at the top of the list. On the left is the PID (process ID). Write it down. Exit `top` with Q key. Now type `pstree -aps 9999` where 9999 is the PID you wrote down.

Comment: I finally captured another offending sleep hogging CPU. Since my first post other processes have been acting the same. They were gvfst, systemd and dbus-demon. Below is from sleep process ID 20143 though as soon as I comanded top CPU started to return to normal.  Code wont fit here with only 300 charactors left.